# How to find required data by looping through JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am totally new to vue js and I just want loop through the json data and want to find that if my required data is available in the file.
this is the sample of json :

```
[
{
    "id": "text-5",
    "widget": "hello",
    "params": {
        "0": "section-right",
        "name": "Right",
        "id": "section",
        "description": "",
        "class": "",
        "after_title": "",
        "widget_id": "text-5"
    },
    "instance": {
        "title": "St",
        "text": "",
        "filter": false,
        "sidebar": "se-right",
        "sidebar-order": 0,
        "inherited": "yes",
        "number": 0
    }
},
{
    "id": "text-5",
    "widget": "hello",
    "params": {
        "0": "section-right",
        "name": "Right",
        "id": "section",
        "description": "",
        "class": "",
        "after_title": "",
        "widget_id": "text-5"
    },
    "instance": {
        "title": "Twitter Feed",
        "twitteruser": "Stei",
        "sidebar": "sectht",
        "sidebar-order": "4"
    }
}]
```

I just want to loop through and find if "instance" contains the value twitteruser.

I tried this code:

```
const data = JSON.parse(res).data
console.log(data[0].instance)
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Vue.js?

Comment: What you shared isn't valid JSON. Can you share the actual JSON you're using and the code you've written so far?

Comment: updated the json file and i am trying to access the "instance" values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can iterate with following way ..

```
    <script>
    var json_data = [
    {
        "id": "text-5",
        "widget": "hello",
        "params": {
            "0": "section-right",
            "name": "Right",
            "id": "section",
            "description": "",
            "class": "",
            "after_title": "",
            "widget_id": "text-5"
        },
        "instance": {
            "title": "St",
            "text": "",
            "filter": false,
            "sidebar": "se-right",
            "sidebar-order": 0,
            "inherited": "yes",
            "number": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "text-5",
        "widget": "hello",
        "params": {
            "0": "section-right",
            "name": "Right",
            "id": "section",
            "description": "",
            "class": "",
            "after_title": "",
            "widget_id": "text-5"
        },
        "instance": {
            "title": "Twitter Feed",
            "twitteruser": "Stei",
            "sidebar": "sectht",
            "sidebar-order": "4"
        }
    }];


    for( var i = 0; i < json_data.length; i++) {

        if(typeof json_data[i].instance == 'object' && typeof json_data[i].instance.twitteruser != 'undefined'){
            console.log(json_data[i].instance.twitteruser);
        }

    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `data` is an array parsed from your JSON you can do this:

```
var filtered = data.filter(function(item) {
   return item.instance && item.instance.twitteruser  
})
```

`filtered` will be a new array with only those elements that have a `twitteruser`

If you just want to know whether is exists, you can test for the length of `filtered`

```
if (filtered.length > 0) {
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have an array of objects, each of which contains another object under the `instance` key, and you want to find out if any of those `instance` objects contain the key `twitteruser`. Just write a `for` loop and check:

```js
const data = [{
    "id": "text-5",
    "widget": "hello",
    "params": {
      "0": "section-right",
      "name": "Right",
      "id": "section",
      "description": "",
      "class": "",
      "after_title": "",
      "widget_id": "text-5"
    },
    "instance": {
      "title": "St",
      "text": "",
      "filter": false,
      "sidebar": "se-right",
      "sidebar-order": 0,
      "inherited": "yes",
      "number": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "text-5",
    "widget": "hello",
    "params": {
      "0": "section-right",
      "name": "Right",
      "id": "section",
      "description": "",
      "class": "",
      "after_title": "",
      "widget_id": "text-5"
    },
    "instance": {
      "title": "Twitter Feed",
      "twitteruser": "Stei",
      "sidebar": "sectht",
      "sidebar-order": "4"
    }
  }
];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i].instance.twitteruser !== undefined) {
    console.log("Found it at index " + i + ".");
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Might be worth checking if  `data.instance` is defined to prevent crash if an element has no `instance` member.

Comment: Yeah, depends on how strong the assumption is that `data[i].instance` exists for all `data[i]`. (It might be preferable to crash if you consider the lack of `.instance` to be an error.)